# Node8 - async /await feature with node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I have been trying to use the new `async/await` feature of Node 8 with `node-mysql module`. Have been partial successful in incorporating `async/await` with `mysql`. When I create a cluster pool connection with `node-mysql` client I am unable to do this without the `callback`. If I write `callback` I am able to get the data from MySQL but when I am using `async/await` I am getting weird errors. Although I have been able to write the `getConnection function` in `async/await` form but no luck with the connection.query part. Can anybody help in this context ?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
var poolCluster = mysql.createPoolCluster();
var masterConfig = {...};
var slaveConfig1 = {...};
poolCluster.add('MASTER', masterConfig);
poolCluster.add('SLAVE1', slaveConfig1);<br>
poolCluster.getConnection = util.promisify(poolCluster.getConnection());<br>
module.exports.PoolCluster = poolCluster;<br>

//connect-cluster-pool.js

var poolClusterSrv = require('../pool-cluster');<br>
async fetchRecord() {<br>
        let queryStr = 'select * from customers';<br>
        console.log("inside fetchRecord()...");<br>
        try {<br>
            let connection = await <br>poolClusterSrv.PoolCluster.getConnection('SLAVE1'); --<b>this is working</b> <br>
            console.log("Connected to SLAVE1::", connection.threadId); 
 //getting new threadId every time
 let results = await util.promisify(connection.query(queryStr)); 
 //this is not working / working only with callback</b> <br>
            console.log(results);<br>
            return results;<br>
        }<br>
        catch (error) {<br>
            console.log("error in fetchRecord()::", error);<br>
        }<br>
    }<br>
```

Comment: Please remove the `br` tags from your code and use the `{ }` symbol in the WYSIWYG editor to format your question into a readable manner.

Comment: Can you post the working syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`util.promisify` should work on any function that uses Node-style, error-first callbacks (unless there is code that relies on function arity, which is rare). If a function is a method that relies on the context, it should be executed with same context as original one.

`util.promisify(poolCluster.getConnection())` and `util.promisify(connection.query(queryStr))` are mistakes. It's a function and not its result that should be promisified.

Instead, it should be:

```
poolCluster.getConnection = util.promisify(poolCluster.getConnection);
...
connection.query = util.promisify(connection.query);
let results = await connection.query(queryStr); 
...
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest to stick to promise-based packages where possible to avoid such hindrances. Another answer already mentions one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that query is a method, not a function. It has this bound in context and your promisify loses it. I don't know what your promisify implemention is, but pify supports promisifying the whole object and then call the method. Alternatively:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => connection.query(..., (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result)))
```

EDIT:

Use this package instead of mysql: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using promise it works.But I wanted to do this without using any kind of call back. Simply using async/await. Is there any way to achieve that ?